# What is Mathematical formulation of entropic Gravitational force?

Tags: gravity, entropy, holographic-principle

There are people proposing the possibility of using entropic force to explain the gravity force between objects.
The emphasis is that entropy is more fundamental than energy.
It is the closest study as entropy is closely related to information.
What is Mathematical formulation of [entropic Gravitational force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity)?

> ... It implies that gravity is not a fundamental interaction, but an emergent phenomenon which arises from the statistical behavior of microscopic degrees of freedom encoded on a holographic screen...

Comment: This question could use clarification.  Have you read the Verlinde paper [http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0785] and need clarification?  Are you looking for a low-level explanation?

Comment: I thought the article *was* the low-level explanation...

Comment: i am looking for Mathematical formulation, low/high-level make no difference

Comment: [what polemicists would say](http://www.sciencecartoonsplus.com/gallery/math/math07.gif)

Comment: @Guest: what these replies are trying to say is that this idea is very vague and hence has no mathematical formulation. I wish it had a physical formulation. The best there is maybe is Ted Jacobson's derivation of the Einstein's equations from the assumption that horizon areas are proportonal to entropy and application of thermodynamic laws to this. See here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bekenstein-Hawking+entropy#Jacobson95 This is a solid argument which, after one accepts the assumptions, should be mathematically rigorous. But if from that it follows that "gravity is an entropic force" is...

Comment: ...is another question. And an ill-defined one, to my mind.

Comment: *"i am looking for Mathematical formulation, low/high-level make no difference"* suggests that you are not taking the question seriously.

Comment: @dmckee
"i am looking for Mathematical formulation, low/high-level make no difference" suggests that i can handle high-level answers.