# What is Verlinde's statistical description of gravity as an entropic force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, statistical-mechanics, entropy

What is Verlinde's statistical description of gravity as an [entropic force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity) leads to the correct inverse square distance law of attraction between classical bodies?

[image: inverse square distance law of attraction between classical bodies]

Comment: In what ways does the [wikipedia page on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropic_gravity) (from whence you got that figure, which you have not credited) fail to answer your question. Have you looked at the references wikipedia cites?

Comment: Probably also worth reading the comments on [an earlier question here on Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4289/).

Comment: How does this differ from [your earlier question on the same topic](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75385/)?